# Can I restore database clickhouse with help binary dump file?

Tags: clickhouse

I have docker container with clickhouse database. And I have backups from our production. But I tried many cases with restore. When I using command (in container): `clickhouse-client --format Raw --file 21_02_04_db.backup`, I get error  `Bad arguments: unrecognised option '--file'`. Okay, I tried without this option: `clickhouse-client --format Raw < 21_02_04_db.backup`  and I get an error:

`Code: 62. DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 1 ('') (line 1, col 1): �TimDateTime�#�]�{�]�k�]u �]0&�] 9�]�-�]��]�I�]U��]���]yy�]���]�\�]�\�]��]{B�]�j�]v)�]�d�]J��]�F�]�]�]��]t%�]t%�]���]��]F?�]�B�]��]W3�]��]E��]P��]a�. Unrecognized token: '' I use other backups but in many cases I get similar error. Maybe someone tried restore backup clickhouse with help binary data? I try many cases but I didn't search solution.`

Comment: how did you backup database - using [clickhouse-backup](https://github.com/AlexAkulov/clickhouse-backup#clickhouse-backup)-tool?

Answer (score 3):

it looks like a Native format

it should something like

```
clickhouse-client -q 'insert into mytable format Native' < 21_02_04_db.backup
```

Comment: Okay, but if i have backup whole database, if i will insert in some table, so i will get only filled one table and data for this table? Or my dump will fill all data in one table?

Comment: Clickhouse does not have a backup for the whole database.